# Use flake8 on SConstruct files (from scons)

Tags: scons, flake8

I want to use `flake8` to verify scons files (`SConstruct`, `SConscript`). Because `scons` implicitly imports the SCons module some names are available by default, like `Program`, `Glob`, `Command`. flake8 does not know about them and drops "undefined name 'Glob' [F821]" warnings.

How could I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

For the implicit imports I've used, you can make them explicit with, e.g.:

```
from SCons.Script import (Command,
                          Glob,
                          Program)
```